Error sqlsrv en PHP
si me pudieran apoyar con esto, me marca error en el SQLSRV

Tengo PHP 8.3 DE ARQUITECTURA 64 BITS, deje en la carpeta EXT los archivos DLL y en php.ini habilite extension_dir = "ext" y agregue las lineas:


En la info de PHP ya me aparecen los drivers


No se si seria otra cosa

PHP TS (Thread Safe) y PHP NTS (Non Thread Safe) son dos versiones con un funcionamiento interno distinto. Puedes ver detalles de las diferencias acá y acá.
En otras palabras, si es para PHP y Apache, es TS. Para CLI y scripting en windows puede ser cualquiera. Para Windows y IIS es NTS.
En tu caso la instalación que tienes es NTS, entonces los errores son porque no puede cargar las librerías TS. Las librerías NTS si fueron cargadas correctamente.
La solución es eliminar las librerías SQLServer TS y eliminar las entradas del php.ini que hacen referencia a las mismas, y ya no tendrás esos errores.

Gracias, quietando las librerias TS, ya no me marca error, solo una duda me sigue apareciendo  undefined function 'sqlsrv_connect en el codigo.

@MonAlcaraz Espero no hayas eliminado php_sqlsrv_83_nts_x64.dll de las extensiones ni de php.ini. Si está todo correcto, entonces sqlsrv necesita SQLServer Native Client instalado. Sin embargo veo que el Native Client está obsoleto y lo cambiaron a MS OLE DB Driver for SQL Server. Instalar este para SQL Server 2019 o superior.

Te agradezco mucho!, tambien lo que agregue fue en Archivo -> preferencias -> Configuración busque  "@ext:bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client" y en STUBS agregue sqlsrv y pdo_sqlsrv.
